# Is there a way to implement CRUD actions using phonegap?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, sails.js

If have a web app and built in nodejs (sails) and I want to create the same app for mobile using phonegap and local storage (sqlite), is there a way to implement the CRUD actions in the mobile app without programming the DB creation, queries, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for abstraction layer so that you wouldn't need to handle the database connection by yourself? If so, I haven't actually came across with any such framework, nor was I able to find one with quite extensive googling. It may be because it is still quite rare to use the SQLite, especially on normal web browsers. Also, it is quite trivial to write those operation by yourself and thus you should be able to do it quite easily.

Comment: Yeah, is really easy I know, but if you have a really complex/large db model it will takes a lot of time! Thanks!!